# Assigning the values returned by a query to multiple textboxes c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

Guys i have a query that is returning a number of tax codes.(depending on document number chosen)

```
 //call method DoQuery and assign returned result to DataReader
DataReader = DoQuery("select oa.[OtherAmountCode] as 'Tax code'
             FROM [Biatss_PC_SRV].[Pax].[SalesDocumentOtherAmount] as oa 
             INNER JOIN [Biatss_PC_SRV].[Pax].[SalesRelatedDocumentInformation]
                 as rd on oa.RelatedDocumentGuid = rd.RelatedDocumentGuid 
             INNER JOIN  [Biatss_PC_SRV].[Pax].[SalesDocumentHeader] as h 
                 on rd.HdrGuid = h.HdrGuid 
             where h.DocumentNumber = '"+txtTicketNumber.Text.ToString()+"'");
//check DataReader
if (DataReader == null)
{
   DataReader.Close();
   DataReader.Dispose();
}
else
{
    if (DataReader.HasRows)
    {
        ReaderResult.Clear();
        while (DataReader.Read())
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < DataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (DataReader.IsDBNull(i))
                {
                    string CaseNull = "";
                    ReaderResult.Add(CaseNull);
                }
                else
                {
                    //put results in LIST<>
                    ReaderResult.Add(DataReader.GetString(i));                                       
                }
            }
        }                             

         //I HAVE TO ASSIGN THE VALUES RETURNED TO textBox1 - textBox5 HERE

    }
    else
    {
        DataReader.Close();
        DataReader.Dispose();
    }
    DataReader.Close();
    DataReader.Dispose();
}
```

I have 5 text boxes. I cant figure out how to assign the tax codes to the textboxes.

I tried the IF-ELSE (taking as reference the number of rows in datareader) but by this method i have no way to delegate the outputs to different text boxes.

Any idea of how to achieve this goal?

Comment: Look into **SQL injection** http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all textboxes in an array. Make sure that they are in the same order as your fields are.

```
var textBoxes = new TextBox[] {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5};

for (int i = 0; i < DataReader.FieldCount; i++)
{
  if (DataReader.IsDBNull(i))
  {
    string CaseNull = "";
    ReaderResult.Add(CaseNull);
  }
  else
  {
    //put results in LIST<>
    ReaderResult.Add(DataReader.GetString(i));
  }

  // put data i onto textbox i
  textBoxes[i].Text = DataReader.GetString(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I HAVE TO ASSIGN THE VALUES RETURNED TO textBox1 - textBox5 HERE
textBox1.Text = ReaderResult.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
textBox2.Text = ReaderResult.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
textBox3.Text = ReaderResult.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
textBox4.Text = ReaderResult.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
textBox5.Text = ReaderResult.ElementAtOrDefault(4);
```

However, that depends on if your reader contains only one record with 5 fields or if it contains multiple records with n-fields. In that case you need to clarify your question.

Side-note: you should always use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection or localization issues, so instead of

```
... where h.DocumentNumber = '"+txtTicketNumber.Text.ToString()+"'"
```

this

```
... where h.DocumentNumber = @TicketNumber"
```

and you should modify your `DoQuery` method to allow to pass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of textboxes, and assign the result in a loop :

```
var tbs = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 };
for(int index = 0; index < ReaderResult.Count, index++)
{
    if(index < tbs.Count)
    {
        tbs[index].Text = ReaderResult[index];
    }
}
```

An advice, your code can be simplify using the `IDisposable` and `using` pattern :

```
using (var DataReader = DoQuery(""))
{
    if (DataReader.HasRows)
    {
        ReaderResult.Clear();
        while (DataReader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (DataReader.IsDBNull(i))
                {
                    string CaseNull = "";
                    ReaderResult.Add(CaseNull);
                }
                else
                {
                    //put results in LIST<>
                    ReaderResult.Add(DataReader.GetString(i));

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```